# How to get the Froala editor's instance in React?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, sharepoint-online, spfx, froala

I want to get the instance of the Froala editor in my React components.

Official Froala documentation does not explain how to do that in React, only jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare a global variable as shown below

```
private _ref: any;
```

> Render the Froala editor:

```
<FroalaEditorComponent
            ref={(ref) => (this._ref= ref)} //create a ref to the instance
            tag="textarea"
            model={html}
            onModelChange={onChange}
            config={config}
        />
```

Now, you can use this global variable across your component to get the Froala editor's instance. Something like below.

```
const GetContent = () => {
       alert(this._ref.editor.html.get());
    };
```

To test it, call the function on a button click:

`<button type="button" onClick={GetContent}>Get Content</button>`

Answer (score 1):

You can also try with:

```
var editor = document.getElementsByTagName('FroalaEditorComponent')[0]['data-froala.editor']
```

or the jQuery way:

```
var editor = $('FroalaEditorComponent')[0]['data-froala.editor']
```